# Dynamically create Multiple tables in SSRS, each table having dynamically growing rows

Tags: reporting-services

I've just started with SSRS, so this might be a very basic question followed by a little complex question. 
I have a parent table in db e.g.

> Degree (id, title)

and a child table

> Courses(id, title, degreeid)

What I'm trying to see in SSRS report is list of all Degrees (as a seperate table with degree title in header) and list of all its courses (as rows in that table) with last row containing. Something like

[image]
and these tables keep on repeating.

I've been playing with List for degrees, containing table for rows, but not sure how to assign courses dataset to table that takes degreeid as input from parent dataset.

This might be a basic question, but I get further confused when the table rows (courses) contain fields that needs to be calculated external to the SSRS e.g. they are not in database instead they are calculated from an external .net base application.

Alternatively, In my .Net web application I can create full hierarchy of parent, child database fields + calculated fields, but not sure how to pass this .Net based matrix to the SSRS report.

Currently creating this whole report in .net and rendering that as image in SSRS  is not an option. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure how complicated your dataset could be, but you can try to use one dataset to hold both degrees and courses data, then the method list for degree containing table for courses should work.

Comment: Can you post your parent and child table definitions  and your dataset design?

Comment: "Reports" in report server automatically grow -you need do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at matrix component this allows simple addition of row and column totals.

Comment: The reason for having .net end calculated fields was the nature of the tables, where column names for table1 were being determined by values in column2 i.e. something like [link] (http://i.imgur.com/o5NOU3L.png). Anyway I had to use dynamic query to create the dataset and using List i'm finally able to get the report displayed as needed.